# Preventing Single.php from showing all blog posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a single.php template but it shows all blogs posts. How do I prevent it from showing all posts:

Below is my code:

```
<?php $args = array('post_type' => 'realweddings');
      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <h1 class="post-heading entry-title"><span class="left-hanger"><?php the_title(); ?>   </span></h1>
         <section class="overview">         
            <?php the_content(); ?>         
        </section>      
        <?php endif;?>  
        <?php comments_template(); ?>
        </article>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: Just add a `break;` before `endwhile;` this will make it just show 1, thus answering your question :).  I jest... how do you want the results filtered?  By a number displayed, a predicate?  We don't have any details about the data set that you have or how you want to filter it.

Comment: Thank adding `break;` worked

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct question is, why am I using `WP_Query` to construct my loop in single.php. Frankly, I can't answer both.

Your problem is your custom query and the straight forward answer is, delete your custom query. You should **never** use a custom query in place of the main query. The main query is very specific on templates as it uses the URL to set the arguments in the main query, which is in fact also just a normal `WP_Query`

Just use the normal loop, that should fix your issue. A custom query is not the way to solve an issue with the main query